# Hashtag followed after by a regular text

Tags: python, regex, tweets

I want to check if a hashtag is followed by a regular text or another hashtag in a python string. 
for example for the case:

```
"my adjectives names #Day #Night which are in the description"
```

, I get false, because after the first hashtag comes again a hashtag. 
But in other cases for example

```
"my adjectives names #Day which is in the description"
```

I will get true.
How can I do that with regular expression operations in Python?

I tried:

```
tweet_text = "my adjectives names #Day #Night which are in the description"
pattern = re.findall(r'\B#\w*[a-zA-Z0-9]+\B#\w*[a-zA-Z0-9]*', tweet_text)
print(pattern)
```

but it doesn't give me any outputs.

Comment: It would be very helpful to show us some code...

Comment: Which of the two types of hashtags do you actually want to match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example from the interpreter:

```
>>> import re
>>> pat = re.compile(r'(#\w+\s+){2,}')
>>>
>>> text = 'my adjectives names #Day  which are in the description'
>>> pat.search(text)
>>>
>>> text = 'my adjectives names #Day #Night which are in the description'
>>> pat.search(text)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(20, 32), match='#Day #Night '>
```

Comment: exactly what I was searching for. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

For hashtags which are *not* followed by another hashtag use:

```
input = "my adjectives names #Day #Night which are in the description"
matches = re.findall(r'#[^#\s]+\b(?!\s+#[^#]+)', input)
print(matches)

['#Night']
```

And for hashtags which *are* followed by another hashtag, just replace the negative lookahead with a positive one:

```
matches = re.findall(r'#[^#\s]+\b(?=\s+#[^#]+)', input)
print(matches)

['#Day']
```